# Convert object function to function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm trying convert a object function to function pointer but can't get it, i've done something like this, simple example:

```
typedef struct
{
    int v1;

    int DoSome(int a)
    {
        return v1 * a;
    }
} strx;


int main()
{
    strx a; // instance...
    a.v1 = 2;


    std::function<int(strx* instance, int value)> DoSome = std::mem_fn(&strx::DoSome);

    cout << DoSome(&a, 4) << endl; // 16 ok 

    int(*pDoSome)(strx* instance, int value) = (int(*)(strx*, int))std::mem_fn(&strx::DoSome); // syntax error

    // ptr method...
    pDoSome(&a ,4);

    return 0;
}
```

and i have obtained something like:

> main.cpp [Error] invalid cast from type 'std::_Mem_fn' to type 'int (*)(strx*, int)'

How i can do correctly the casting?

Comment: `std::function<strx* instance, int value>` is invalid.  Do you mean `std::function<int (strx*, int)>`?

Comment: @aschepler yes, i've fixed, thanks.

Comment: You don't need to use `typedef` in C++. Just use `struct strx { ... }`, because class and struct names automatically become types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  This is why `std::function` is more flexible than pointers to functions.

Answer (score 1):

> How i can do correctly the casting?

You cannot. Object pointers and function pointers are totally different concepts. Only `nullptr` can be used to initialize both types of pointers. Otherwise, they are not guaranteed to be compatible.

I suggest sticking with the `std::function`.

If you must have a function pointer, you have to use a non-member function or a `static` member function of a class.

E.g.

```
int doSomeFunction(strx* instance, int value)
{
   // Use instance any way you please.
   // ...
   //
   return 0;
}

int main()
{
    strx a; // instance...
    a.v1 = 2;

    int(*pDoSome)(strx* instance, int value) = doSomeFunction;

    // ptr method...
    pDoSome(&a ,4);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok, i can't do that becuase i need the pointer function for do a detour, but thanks a lot.